# How many combinations are possible for choosing two letters from the alphabet with replacement?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have two slots _ , _ to fill with letters of the alphabet how many doubletons can I create? e.g. (a,a) , (a, g), (f, e), etc...

I feel the answer should be $26^2$ aka ${ 26 \choose 1} * { 26 \choose 1}$, but why would ${ 52 \choose 2}$ be incorrect?

Comment: An answer of $\binom{52}{2}$ would be correct in the scenario that you have the twenty-six lowercase letters as well as twenty-six uppercase letters and you don't care about the order in which they appear.  An answer of $26^2$ would be correct in the scenario that you only have lowercase letters and you *do* care what order they appear and replacement is allowed.  @JonathanZ is incorrect.  The scenario that he refers to, without replacement and order ignored would only have $\binom{26}{2}$ outcomes.  Another scenario, with replacement and order ignored would have $\binom{26}{2}+26$ outcomes.

Comment: Rather than looking for a formula to use, always looking to try to find some permutation or combination formula, I highly encourage you to instead learn and understand *where* the formulas come from and how to create the formulas.  In this case, [the rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) is exactly what is used.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Yep, I mis-read the '52' in the top! My comment's wrong, so I'll delete it. If you include 'without replacement' to your comment it should probably be a full fledged answer. (And I'll second your comment on understanding where the formulas come from.)